# Django-react native : request failed with status code 400

Tags: android, django, react-native, mobile, axios

i m trying to POST an image from react-native frontend using android emulator to my api but i m getting this error :  Request failed with status code 400

this is my axios request :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const uploaded = new FormData()
  uploaded.append('image_file',image)
  axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/upload/', uploaded)
      .then(response => console.log(response));
}, []);
```

this is my Views.py :

```js
def methodes(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.method=='POST':
            image_file=request.data['image_file']
            #title=request.data['title']
            Upload.objects.create(image_file=image_file)
            serializer=ImageSerializer(data=request.FILES['image'], required=False)
            if serializer.is_valid():
               serializer.save()
               return HttpResponse({'message':'ok'},status=200) 
            return HttpResponse({'message':'error'},status=400)
```